# jQuery Dialog showing only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having a pickle with my jQuery. The situation is as follows:
I'm having a page loaded (main page). When clicked on a  certain element, a div is opened loaded with another page(page1). Within this loaded page, I have a button, which opens a dialog, containing another loaded page (page2).

This all works fine, for one time. When I close the dialog, it doesn't appear again when clicked on the button on page1.

I've searched the interwebs, but the solutions are not helping me. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. It's a very common problem, but I seem to have the code right, right?

This is my code (the usefull part, anyway):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#editdialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 600,

    });

    $(".editfreight").one("click", function(){
        $("#editdialog").load("inc/ajax/editfreight_ajax.php?id=" + $(this).data("freight"));
        $("#editdialog").dialog("open");

    });


});

</script>

<div id="editdialog" style="display: hidden"></div>
```

Well, i'm hoping someone can help me out here! I've also tried this:

```
$(".editfreight").one("click", function(){
$("#editdialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 600,
                    close: function() {
                          $("#editdialog").dialog("destroy")

        });
        $("#editdialog").load("inc/ajax/editfreight_ajax.php?id=" + $(this).data("freight"));
    $("#editdialog").dialog("open");
)};
```

This way, I figured I initiate the dialog when I click the button (and not on pageload), and destroy the instance when I close the dialog. Apparently this isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler attachment should be `on("click")`, not `one("click")`, `one` will only trigger once

```
$(".editfreight").on("click", function(){
});
```

see `one` doc: http://api.jquery.com/one/

> `one()`: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

Comment: This did the trick. I used one() because Dreamweaver doesn't recognize on(). Silly mistake. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

Change this and try

```
$(".editfreight").one("click",function(){
```

change to

```
$(".editfreight").click(function(){
```

change this line too

```
close: function() {
     $("#editdialog").dialog("close")
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(".editfreight").one("click", function(){
```

by

```
$(".editfreight").click(function(){
```

[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is designed to work only once.